# React state hook 2D array first element is always empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a 2d array, which I can push elements to. The issue i'm running into is the fact that when i print the contents, there is always a blank element at index 0. I do not know where this is coming from?

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([[]]);
```

// call this code 4 times

```
const updatedArray = [...array, ['test', 'test2']];
setArray(updatedArray);
```

[image]

Comment: You're initialising your state with a nested array, that's where it's coming from. The operation adds the new set of data starting at index 1. Just `useState([]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is

`...array`

since the initial value of the array is
`[]`.

So `array[0]` would be equal to `[]` and you append your new values beginning from `array[1]` on.

What you want to do is `const updatedArray = [['test', 'test2']];` since you do not want the initial value to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this issue occurs with state.
In case of hooks, you should use `useEffect` hook, As below-

```
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Fruit', fruit);
}, [fruit])
```

This saved my day, Hope will help you too!!!